# I have a casascius coin -- how can I sell it?

Tags: sell-bitcoins, physical-coins

I was given an actual casascius bitcoin minted in 2011 as a tip, and I'd like to know where I can exchange it for US dollars.

How would I extract the private key from this coin to gain access to the digital bitcoins if I were to sell them online?

Comment: By physical Bitcoin, do you mean one of these? https://www.casascius.com/

Comment: related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17768/i-bought-a-bunch-of-2009-bitcoins-the-actual-coin-how-can-i-cash-the-coin-in

Comment: that looks like the one. with the code on the back

Comment: I was hoping to  just be able to take it to the bank to exchange it. It's the 1B brassy one.

Answer (score 3):

You have two routes here:

#### Sell the physical Bitcoin

Don't remove the sticker on the back. Use a website like [localbitcoins](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13117/how-do-i-buy-bitcoins-safely-face-to-face) to sell it to someone near you.

Some people might want a physical Bitcoin, especially since they're not being made anymore.

#### Sell the Bitcoin 'contained' within the physical coin.

Peel off the sticker on the back. Inside will be a code that lets you spend the Bitcoin. (I recommend using [Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/wallet) as your e-wallet.) You can sell the Bitcoin [online](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12419/good-way-to-sell-bitcoins-online) or [locally](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13117/how-do-i-buy-bitcoins-safely-face-to-face).

The remaining brass part is mostly worthless.

Comment: I was looking for more of a "physical walk in place" to take it to rather than all the online jargon wallet things. My bank should be able to cash this for me, right?

Comment: @user21748 No, they won't.

Comment: Well, they said they would. Okay, Thanks.

Comment: @user21748 let us know how that works out but I can't see it happening. I'd sell the coin whole on eBay. Anyone not into Bitcoin either won't care, or won't pay market rate